# Unable to click on hidden AirPlay button element on Safari (mac) using the selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, safari

As part of testing using Python and Selenium, I intend to open a youtube link using selenium and want to click on the "AirPlay"button in order to send it across to the Apple TV.
Initially I had the problem with the element being hidden but that was taken care of using the ActionChains. The script executes but I do not see click being executed on the video played by which I could see the AppleTv name show up.

Below is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import os , sys

server_url = "http://10.0.10.4:4444/wd/hub"
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.SAFARI
driver = webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities=capabilities, 
command_executor=server_url)
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_YhrCp9m14k")

#air_play = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="move_player"]/div[28]/div[2]/div[2]/button[6]')))
air_play = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'ytp-airplay-button')))
#air_play = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="text"]')))

#air_play = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.ytp-ariplay-button')
hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(air_play)
hover.perform()

hover1 = ActionChains(driver).click_and_hold(air_play).perform()
```

The html element is as follows:

```
<button class="ytp-airplay-button ytp-button" title="AirPlay" style=""><svg 
height="100%" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 36 36" width="100%"><use 
class="ytp-svg-shadow" NS1:href="#ytp-id-27"></use><path class="ytp-svg-
fill" d="M12,28 L24,28 L18,22 L12,28 Z M27,9 L9,9 C7.9,9 7,9.9 7,11 L7,23 
C7,24.1 7.9,25 9,25 L13,25 L13,23 L9,23 L9,11 L27,11 L27,23 L23,23 L23,25 
L27,25 C28.1,25 29,24.1 29,23 L29,11 C29,9.9 28.1,9 27,9 L27,9 Z" id="ytp-
id-27"></path></svg></ button>
```

The XPATH is as follows:

```
//*[@id="movie_player"]/div[28]/div[2]/div[2]/button[6]
```

The CSS Selector is as follows:

```
#movie_player > div.ytp-chrome-bottom > div.ytp-chrome-controls > div.ytp-
right- controls > button.ytp-airplay-button.ytp-button
```

Can someone help with as to why the button does not get clicked and show up the available Airplay options?

## Before hovering over the video.

[image: Before hovering over the video]

## After hovering over the video and clicking on the AirPlay button.

[image: After hovering over the video and clicking on the AirPlay button]

Comment: I don't see the Airplay option. I'm assuming I'm missing some component that triggers it to show up. Can you edit your question and post the relevant HTML?

Comment: @ JeffC. I hope i have provided the required information you needed. Maybe i need to mention that this element is seen on the Safari browser on the mac books. I have not tried it on a Windows installed Safari browser.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have Safari on a Mac so I can't repro this myself but I'm guessing the issue (from your screenshot) is that the icon isn't visible until the video area is hovered. By design, Selenium will not interact with elements that a user can't see. There are a couple ways to do this.

1. The user way... hover the video, hover the icon, and then click the icon. If you are trying to simulate a user, this is the method you want to use.

   ```
   from selenium import webdriver
   from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

   video = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("video")
   ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(video).perform()
   WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[title='AirPlay']")).click()
   ```
2. The non-user way... click on it with JSE. With JSE we can click any element, visible or not. No user can click an invisible element so if you are trying to simulate a user, don't use this... use #1.

   ```
   airplayButton = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[title='AirPlay']")
   driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", airplayButton);
   ```

Comment: I tried both the steps. The 2nd step seems to be working. I can see the pop up with the available airplay devices show up. Will spend some time on this to make the user way work. Any more ideas would be truly useful. Also, the correction for the 2nd step would be "driver.execute_script(....)".

Comment: It's possible that for the first step that you would need a wait between the hover and the click. Updated answer and corrected your correction... too many languages in my head... good catch. ;)

Comment: I tried the 1st step using the WebDriverWait but interestingly I get the TimeoutException waiting for the element to be clickable. On checking the page I noticed that before the button gets visible the "title = AirPlay" shows up on the html but when i hover the mouse over the AirPlay button the title=Airplay goes missing. I have attached the snapshots as well. File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/s‌​upport/wait.py", line 80, in until raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message.

Comment: Tried using XPATH, "//button[@class='ytp-airplay-button ytp-button']" even this did not help.

Comment: You could use the id on the `PATH`, ytp-id-32, and see if that works.

Comment: Just did some basic testing, like clicking on the video to pause it and after few seconds click on full screen button to enlarge it, on chrome and they all work. But the same do not work on Safari. Looks like i am missing something basic to make it work with Safari. Safari version is 11.0 and the WebDriver version is 2.48.0